# function to_date with oracle and hql hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I work with oracle  and hql

I have this query  :

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM RequestHealthCertificate  rs  WHERE rs.requestDateHcertif between to_date(:pstartDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date(:pendDate,'MM/DD/YYYY')");

        //Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM RequestHealthCertificate  rs  WHERE rs.requestDateHcertif between :pstartDate and :pendDate");

        query.setParameter("pstartDate", startDate);
        query.setParameter("pendDate", endDate);
```

this is an example of date which will be converted using **to_date**  **Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013**

but when I test I have this error :

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ORA-01858: Caractère non numérique trouvé à la place d'un caractère numérique

09:07:49,635 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Method execution failed: : org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.3-Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If start and end date are both of type DATE you dont need to convert it. 
You only need to convert if both values are of type string

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that those variables are of type String and not DATE, and they have to have the same format.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this method to set dates than using the to_date.

http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/examples/hql/HQL-date-Between.html